# File name too long on docker

Tags: maven, apache-spark, docker

I'm trying to run Spark on a Docker container:

```
val input = sc.textFile("data/trips/*")

println input

input.map(_.split(",")).count()
```

However, for any code that type I get this error:

```
File name too long
```

After looking here http://timothyfox.net/?p=8 I realised you have to change `pom.xml` or `build.sbt`.

However, my code is part of an exercise that was packaged as a docker container, so I don't know how it's organised. I looked into the docker container and found a `pom.xml` file where I added:

```
<arg>-Xmax-classfile-name</arg>
<arg>128</arg>
```

But nothing changed.

Comment: Do you have access to the Dockerfile, or is it publicly available? Replace "for any code that type I get this error: " with the command (mvn or sbt perhaps?) that produces the error. Review https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4820 to see how it relates to your issue. If the Docker container is privately maintained then you will likely have to get the maintainer of that container to support it.